# Answer count is not aligned horizontally in responsive design

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design

In case of the existence of answers for questions in responsive design the middle block text is slightly (~2px) shifted to the bottom:

> [image: answers down]

This makes me nervous.

Comment: Now I can't unsee it